# Rasberry Pi - b appliances timer

Tags: pi-3

I am facing some problems in making a relay work with a Raspberry Pi by coding it in Python. Most of the tutorials that I have found on the internet use the Raspberry Pi as an input signal and control for the relay but I do not want to do that.

I need the raspberry only for the controlling of the relay (applied to the coil) since I will be using different and more powerful input.

So, the idea is to ground one part of the coil and being able to control the other part (meaning applied a 3,3/5V signal or not depending on the time of the day).
Actually we want to give power to the coil (meaning open the relay) for half an hour every day (from Monday to Sunday, from 9 to 9:30 am).

I am trying with different pins, but nothing happens. Can anyone give me a hand? Thank you very much!

[image]

I have connected already the relay to the permanent 5V signal from Raspberry (pins 2 and 4) and 3.3V (1 and 17 if I am not wrong) and the other one always to the ground (6th).

The problem with these pins is that as far as I know, they can not be controlled. Is it like that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of relay do you have?  Specifically, what are the coil specifications?

Comment: Your question is unclear, BUT just as a warning **directly connecting a relay to the Pi risks damage**. You can not control a relay without additional circuitry.